# Number theory question from today's Pre - RMO

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many positive integers less than 1000 have the property that the sum of the digits of each such number is divisible by 7 and the number itself is divisible by 3?

Comment: Notice that a number if divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of digits is divisible by $3$. Thus the sum of digits has to divisible by $21$. Notice that the largest sum of digits of integers less than 1000 is $9+9+9=27$. Thus you are looking for integers whose sum of digits is exactly $21$

Comment: For example if there is a number 399, it adds upto 21, but won't we add the 2 and 1, which equals 3?

Comment: As I understand the question $399$ is an example. Indeed, the sum of digits is $21$, hence divisible by $7$ and the number $399$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I think there are no solutions as the 21 adds up to 3 which is not divisible by 3.

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment, do we need that $21$ adds up to a number divisible by $3$? Also, $3$ is divisible by $3$. Do you mean that the sum of the digits of the number obtained by taking the sum of digits should also be divisble by $7$? In that case there are no solutions.

Comment: The answer is quite ambiguous. I will let you know the answer interpreted by the question - makers when the the answer key comes out.

Comment: It is quite ambiguous. Anyways, the way I interpreted the question gives $7+6+5+4+3+2+1=7\cdot 4=28$ solutions.

Comment: We are not computing a recursive sum. Sum of the digits of a number of the form 100x + 10y +z is x+y+z.

Answer (score 1):

By my comment above we are looking for three digits such that they sum to exactly $21$. This is possible as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
9+9+3&=&21\\
9+8+4&=&21\\
9+7+5&=&21\\
\vdots&=& \vdots\\
9+3+9&=&21\\
8+9+4&=&21\\
8+8+5&=&21\\
\vdots&=&\vdots\\
8+4+9&=&21\\
7+9+5&=&21\\
\vdots&=&\vdots\\
7+5+9&=& 21\\
\vdots&=&\vdots\\
\end{eqnarray}

Can you spot the pattern in the list? It's not too difficult to count the number of such solutions without writing all of them down. There are $28$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let the number $abc$ be such that it is divisible by $3$ and $a+b+c=7k$ where $k$ is some positive integer. The first condition is equivalent to $a+b+c=3l$ where $l$ is some positive integer. Thus the 2 conditions are:

1. $a+b+c=3l$
2. $a+b+c=7k$

Notice that the maximum possible value of $a+b+c= 9+9+9=27$. Thus, using condition $1$ and $2$, we get $a+b+c=3*7=21$, the number of solutions to which can be found using numerous combinatorics method (Generating functions, dots and sticks method, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: is **28 positive integers** which are less than 1000 and the sum of the digit is divisible by 7 and itself divisible by 3. Lowest positive integer is 399 and highest is 993. Pattern is like this starting from 3 digit i.e Qty-01 (399), 4 digit i.e Qty-02 (489 & 498), 5 digit i.e Qty-3 (579,588 & 597), 6 digit i.e Qty-4 (669,678,687 & 696),7 digit i.e. Qty-5 ( 759,768,777,786 & 795) 8 digit i.e Qty-6 ( 849,858,867,876,885 & 894), 9 digit i.e. Qty-7 ( 939,948,957,966,975,984 & 993)

Answer (score 0):

Answer = 28

a+b+c = 7k 
abc is also multiply of 3 so a+b+c multiple of both 7 and 3

therefore a+b+c =21

9-a+9-b +9-c =21

a'+b'+c' =6

8C2

Comment: While the $9-x$ trick is neat, you should comply with the principle that different things shall have different names. Your $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $9-a+9-b+9-c=21$ denote numbers that are different from the $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $a+b+c=21$, so they must have different names.

Answer (score 0):

The number has to be a 3-digit number.So if the largest digit,9 occupies unit' and tenth'places,3 alone can be placed in hundredth'place in order to get the sum of the digits to be 21.
Obviously the 1st number is                                               399

```
      the next two numbers are                                     489,498

    the next three numbers are                                 579,588,597

     the next four numbers are                             669,678,687,696


     the next five numbers are                         759,768,777,786,795


      the next six numbers are                     849,858,867,876,885,894


 the last set of seven numbers                  939,948,957,966,975,984,993
```

total number of numbers =1+2+3+4+5+6+7  =28

At the third stage itself it can be seen that A P pattern forms.So we can skip to the last stage and get the last term of this A P and find the sum to get the total number of required  numbers

Comment: Since the range is small (1 to 1000),listing all such numbers is not time consuming.But if the range is wide ,certainly  pattern appears so that we need not list all such numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Answer is 21 because the first number which is multiple of both 7 and 3 is 21

Comment: We know the sum of digit has to be divided by $21$ , it doesn't mean there are $21$ such numbers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).